Was there a comic book moment where Frank Castle acknowledged the Punisher as his intrinsic nature instead of a reactive transformation?
Frank Castle's origin story (in most iterations) is that he became the "Punisher," a vigilante who relentlessly kills criminals and evildoers, after the tragic murder of his family.
I was watching Season 2 of Marvel's The Punisher TV series (2019), and in Episode 9, there was an interesting moment where Frank seemed to have a realization about his true nature. He thought that, despite initially believing he was just an ordinary guy who changed after losing his family, he realized that being the Punisher was always who he truly was deep down.
Here's the relevant dialogue:

Castle: If you had asked me once, I would've told you I was pretty much just like anyone else.
And all I really gave a shit about was that my family was healthy or happy.
But I lost them.
Everything changed.
I thought... I thought I became something different.
But last night... I had a little chat with my wife.
I sat by her grave, and I realized something.
This is always who I was.
And Maria... she knew.
She knew what I was.


Madani: Then what are you asking?
Castle: Let me be what I'm meant to be.

Now, this got me curious. In the comics, has Frank Castle himself (any iteration) ever come to the same realization about the Punisher as in the TV show? That being the Punisher was always Frank Castle's true nature instead of a reactive transformation? If yes, in which comic book or issue was this realization made or revealed?
